# Get the opened state of a file from an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on an Electron application. After downloading an image or `.doc` or `.pdf` file, I open that file in its respective application like Windows PhotoViewer, Ms Word etc... From my Electron app, I want to check whether the file is closed when I close that external application.

I open a file by storing it in local temp path and opened with spawn and exec child processess. That process will be exit after the file is opened successfully, but I also want to get a response after the respective application closes.

My file opening function logic:

```js
if (process.platform == 'win32') {
  try {
    let bat = spawn("cmd.exe", [ "/c", path_local, "argument1", "argumentN" ]);

    bat.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    bat.stderr.on("data", (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    bat.on("exit", (code) => {
      console.log(code);
    });

    return;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
} else {
  shell.openPath(path_local);
}
```

Comment: I tried to edit as best as I can but there are some parts of your question I just can't understand.

Comment: @KJ thanks for the response. i also can't able to find the solution. for example my application download same image 10 times and store it in different folders and opened at 10 instances from photo viewer in windows. unlike the excel files the child process will exit after opening the image. but i want to handle that particular images opened is closed or not and handle that status in my application to close my app also.. is it any way that i can achive this behaviour

Comment: yes if i try to query and find the opened file . it will definitely through access denied error . that way it is not possible .

Comment: i have been trying since a week, but i need to add this functionality some how to my app. because with excel files it is working fine because the child process will continue until the excel file close. but other files it will not work

Comment: @Arkellys for example my application download same image 10 times and store it in different folders and opened at 10 instances from photo viewer in windows. unlike the excel files the child process will exit after opening the image. but i want to handle that particular images opened is closed or not and handle that status in my application to close my app also.. is it any way that i can achive this behaviour

Comment: @KJ it is not possible to access the tasklist find from the nodejs applicatioin . all i can achive from tasklist is the data in kb for that application.. and for the ppid is that command prompt parent and for opening image it will create one child process and that child processs id will be exited after opening the file itslef .

Comment: @KJ .  for excel files the child.on('exit') is hitting after the excel is closed manually . but for other files it is hitting exit after opening the file .